# Using isEqual to test equality of NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I was under the impression that to test the value of an NSNumber you may use isEqual:

However, when I test the value of an NSNumber with an integer value of 38 using the following code, I am getting false instead of true.  Is there a subtlety to this that I am missing?

```
if ([self.adding isEqual:@38]) {
//they are equal
}
else {
//they are unequal
}
```

Of note, when I use if `([self.adding intValue]==38)`, I do get the expected result.

In the debugger the NSNumber shows as `int(38)`.

Comment: And how was constructed `self.adding`? For instance, if it was `@(38.5)`, it won't work, but work if it works when converting to Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-isEqualToNumber:` for a numeric equality test, which is itself tied to the `-compare:` method's notion of equality.

(`NSNumber` is implemented as a class cluster. The guts of the `-isEqual:` method are likely looking at additional subtleties like whether the two instances are from the same actual type or whatever, which might be significant when dealing with storage in a collection but don't help you check for the 38. This is the same reason you should use NSString's `-isEqualToString:` method for the equivalent comparison).

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  Will use the isEqualToNumber henceforth